# Unable to use my 4k monitor at maximum resolution when used with one or two others FHD monitors

Tags: xorg, multiple-monitors, radeon, awesome, 4k-monitor

I would like to use my 40" 4k monitor (Philips BDM4065UC) alongside with two others WUXGA monitors (Dell U2412M).

I can successfully run :

- my main 4k alone at 3840x2160@60Hz,
- or my main 4k at 2560x1440@60Hz with the two others monitors at 1920x1200@60.

As soon as, I try to increase the resolution of my main monitor to 3840x2160 with the two others monitors :

- all the windows of the 4k monitors are grayed out,
- the two others monitors are working correctly,
- the mouse on the 4k monitor is still working,
- I can move windows in and out my 4k screen but I can't see them displayed on the 4k screen.

This setup works correctly on windows.

**My setup :**

- Graphic card : AMD Radeon R7 250X (same issue with 59 280X)
- Driver : radeon (open source, don't want to use fglrx as I only do 2D stuffs)
- Xubuntu 14.04
- Kernel : 3.19.0-22-generic(tried also with 3.16)
- Windows manager : Awesome WM

**My configuration files :**

Script 1 : xrandr script that fails :

```
xrandr --output DisplayPort-0 --pos 1200x0 --rotate normal --rate 60 --mode 3840x2160 --primary && \
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --auto --rotate left --pos 0x0  && \
xrandr --output DVI-0 --rate 60 --mode 1920x1200 --pos 5040x0 --rotate left
```

Script 2 : xrandr script that "works" :

```
xrandr --output DisplayPort-0 --pos 1200x0 --rotate normal --rate 60 --mode 2560x1440 --primary && \
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --auto --rotate left --pos 0x0  && \
xrandr --output DVI-0 --rate 60 --mode 1920x1200 --pos 5040x0 --rotate left
```

**My logs files:**

I have no errors in [/var/log/Xorg.0.log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11914462/).

However when digging in /var/log/syslog, I can see some errors (but are not always reproducible) :

when running Script 1 :

```
pcp kernel: [ 6337.304231] radeon 0000:04:00.0: ffff880390d22800 pin failed
pcp kernel: [ 6337.304231] radeon 0000:04:00.0: ffff880390d22800 pin failed
pcp kernel: [ 6337.350587] radeon 0000:04:00.0: ffff880390d22800 pin failed
pcp kernel: [ 6337.350587] radeon 0000:04:00.0: ffff880390d22800 pin failed
```

when running Script 2 :

```
pcp kernel: [ 6377.757518] radeon 0000:04:00.0: ffff880390d22800 unpin not necessary
pcp kernel: [ 6377.757518] radeon 0000:04:00.0: ffff880390d22800 unpin not necessary
```

It seems to be a kernel or driver issue, but I don't know where to start to debug this.

**Unsuccessfull solutions**:

1/ use a more powerful graphic gard : Radeon R9 280X (note: this works on windows)

2/ use a more recent kernel (3.19.0-22-generic instead of 3.16)

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid
sudo update-grub
```

3/ use a static Xorg configuration file in [/etc/X11/xorg.conf](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11914522/
)

4/ use an [updated radeon driver](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Trusty_Installation_Guide#Updated_Open_Source_Driver_PPA.27s)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers && sudo aptitude update && sudo aptitude upgrade
```

then removed with

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge && sudo ppa-purge ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers && supo aptitude update && sudo aptitude upgrade
```

5/ upgrade to Xubuntu 15.05

same problem, even with kernel 4.0, or latest xorg / ATI packages

6/ test others distributions Mint, Debian

**Partially successfull solutions:**

1/ I finally give a try to the proprieratery driver. I followed the [installation instructions](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Trusty_Installation_Guide#Installing_Catalyst_Manually_.28from_AMD.2FATI.27s_site.29_STABLE).

The all 3 monitors are now using the appropriate screen resolutions.

However, this is now so slooow, moving the mouse is very lagguy, opening two terminal windows takes 5 seconds...

Definitly unusable...

Any hints are welcome,

Regards,

Comment: It seems someone as exactly [the same problem and reported as a bug](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=52330#c8) (see comment 8). However, the solution given here does not work for me (radeon drivers parameters in xorg file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it...

**Triple check** the output of /var/log/Xorg.0.log to remove as most as you can errors and warning. I mispelled one of my output DVI-O instead of DVI-0...

So, if you encounter this problem, the solution seems to be :

Describe as most as you can your configuration in /etc/X11/xorg.conf :

- device section with Options "AccelMethod" "glamor" / Option "ShadowPrimary" / Option "TearFree"
- **all** outputs of your video card and **all** your attached monitors

Here is the fully functionnal version of my [/etc/X11/xorg.conf](http://paste.ubuntu.com/12012809/)