# Dead parts of Display

Tags: multiple-monitors, screen, amd-graphics

I have 3 screens currently active, running through one of my ASUS R9 270X graphics cards, (I did have 2 in but I was getting problems with the display and the ASUS/AMD proprietary drivers crashed my system.)  I now have Ubuntu Mate 15.05 running through a single 270x, which is working fine (It crashes when I try to use 4 for some reason - the screen goes all mosaic on me). 
The problem that I am having now, is Icons are missing from my display, but show up on where the 4th monitor should be on a black background, when I do CTR-ALT-Arrow Key.   Plus also parts of one of my active screen is dead.  I can have a window open on it, and only half or the window responds (the right side).  I dont know what is causing this, does any one have any clues?

`xrandr` output:

```
warren@RIVE:~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3360 x 1950, maximum 16384 x 16384
DisplayPort-0 connected 1680x1050+0+900 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 474mm x 296mm
   1680x1050      60.0*+
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1440x900       75.0     59.9  
   1024x768       75.1     60.0  
   800x600        75.0     60.3  
   640x480        75.0     60.0  
   720x400        70.1  
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-0 connected 1680x1050+1680+900 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 474mm x 296mm
   1680x1050      60.0*+
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1440x900       75.0     59.9  
   1024x768       75.1     60.0  
   800x600        75.0     60.3  
   640x480        75.0     60.0  
   720x400        70.1  
DVI-1 connected 1440x900+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 408mm x 255mm
   1440x900       59.9*+   75.0  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1024x768       75.1     70.1     60.0  
   832x624        74.6  
   800x600        72.2     75.0     60.3     56.2  
   640x480        75.0     72.8     66.7     60.0  
   720x400        70.1
```

Comment: I'm using the 'AMD, Inc [AMD/ATI]:curacao XT [Radeon R9 270X], on the option.  *Using X.Org X server - AMD/ATI Display driver wrapper from xserver-xorg-video-ati (open source, tested)

Comment: I cant see an xorg.conf file in /ect/x11  just an Xwrapper.config

Answer (score 0):

Have you described your devices / monitors configuration in /etc/X11/xorg.conf ?

If not, I would advice you to do so, it was the only way to get my 3 monitors working on Ubuntu 15.04.

You can look at [my question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/650947/unable-to-use-my-4k-monitor-at-maximum-resolution-when-used-with-one-or-two-othe/657237#657237) to see some examples of configuration files, and ways to manage displays through xrandr or xorg.conf.

Additionnaly, if you want more precise help :

- which drivers are you using ? Open source (radeon) or proprietary (fglrx) ?
- what's the result of `xrandr` ?
- what's the result of `lspci | grep VGA` ?
- How are your monitors arranged on you desk ? Describe the position / rotation depending on which connector they use : DisplayPort / DVI-0 / DVI-1.

To know which display is on DVI-O or DVI-1, just run:

```
xrandr --display DVI-0 --off
```

it will disable the display on DVI-0.

To reenable it :

```
xrandr --display DVI-0 --auto
```

Here is a first attempt with all displays in landscape in the order from left to right (DP / DVI-0/ DVI-1), be aware that you need to edit the line BusID with the correct PCI address given by the command `lspci | grep VGA`.

Put these lines in /etc/X11/xorg.conf :

```
Section "ServerLayout"

    Identifier     "home_config"
    Screen      0  "Screen-DisplayPort-0" 0 0
    Screen      1  "Screen-DVI-0" 1680 0
    Screen      2  "Screen-DVI-1" 3360 0

EndSection

Section "Files"

    ModulePath   "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1"
    FontPath     "built-ins"

EndSection

Section "Module"

    Load  "extmod"
    Load  "dri"
    Load  "dri2"
    Load  "dri3"
    Load  "dbe"
    Load  "glx"
    Load  "record"

EndSection

Section "Device"

    Identifier  "R9270X"
    Driver      "radeon"
    BusID       "PCI:4:0:0" #<--- replace here with the PCI adress given by lspci | grep VGA
    Option      "Monitor-DVI-0" "Display-DVI-0"
    Option      "Monitor-DVI-1"  "Display-DVI-1"
    Option      "Monitor-DisplayPort-0" "Display-DisplayPort-0"
    Option     "AccelMethod" "glamor"
    Option      "ModeDebug" "true"

EndSection

Section "Monitor"

    Identifier "Display-DisplayPort-0"
    Option "PreferredMode"  "1680x1050"
    Option "Position" "0 0"
    Option "Enable"  "true"

EndSection

Section "Monitor"

    Identifier "Display-DVI-0"
    Option "PreferredMode"  "1680x1050"
    Option "Position" "1680 0"
    Option "Enable"  "true"
    Option "Primary" "true"

EndSection

Section "Monitor"

        Identifier "Display-DVI-1"
        Option "PreferredMode"  "1440x900"
        Option "Position" "3360 0"
        Option "Enable"  "true"
EndSection


Section "Screen"

    Identifier "Screen-DisplayPort-0"
    Monitor "Display-DisplayPort-0"
    Device "R9270X"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Viewport 0 0
        Depth 24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"

    Identifier "Screen-DVI-0"
    Monitor "Display-DVI-0"
    Device "R9270X"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Viewport 0 0
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection

EndSection

Section "Screen"

    Identifier "Screen-DVI-1"
    Monitor "Display-DVI-1"
    Device "R9270X"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
            Viewport 0 0
    EndSubSection

EndSection

Section "DRI"
    Mode 0666
EndSection
```

If something goes wrong and you can't access your display manager:

1. reboot in recovery mode
2. rename the file xorg.conf : `sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.bak`
3. reboot : `sudo reboot` (or restart your display manager `sudo service lightdm restart` for example)
4. provide error logs : `cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | pastebinit` and `cat /var/log/Xorg.1.log | pastebinit`

Good  luck !

Comment: Please see above.  and thanks for your help it is appreciated.

Comment: just added two others questions to help me give you an appropriate xorg.conf file