# How to enable amd discrete graphics card?

Tags: drivers, graphics, ati, dell, radeon

I bought a new laptop, and have a problem with graphics card driver. I've been trying to fix problem for few days, please, help me if you know the answer.
Hardware: Dell Inspiron 15 3541 with A6-6310 QUAD-CORE with Radeon R4 Graphics. 4GB Memory. Discrete graphic AMD R5 M230 2GB card.

For now, Ubuntu says that I have only 3,3 GB of RAM. As I understand other 700 Mb are used by enabled integrated AMD R4.

I want to use discrete card with its 2 GB of RAM and use all of my 4GB RAM.

I've tried to install proprietary drivers from AMD site. But Discrete card still doesnt't work and invisible.

The output of lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|Display' terminal command:

```
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Mullins [Radeon APU A4-6000 with R2 Graphics]
Subsystem: Dell Device 0658
Kernel driver in use: fglrx_pci
--
01:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun PRO [Radeon HD 8500M Series] (rev ff)
Kernel driver in use: fglrx_pci
Kernel modules: fglrx
```

when I triedcommand lspci -v it showed this output:

```
01:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun PRO [Radeon HD 8500M Series] (rev ff) (prog-if ff)
!!! Unknown header type 7f
Kernel driver in use: fglrx_pci
Kernel modules: fglrx
```

I would really appreciate your help.
Evgeniy.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: Ok, I've just added the output. Evgeniy.

Comment: And if you run `sudo amdcccle` can you switch to discrete card?

Comment: no. I can't. It shows only integrated one.

Comment: And how did you install the driver?

Comment: System Settings -> Additional Drivers and installed proprietary driver. But it didnt help. I tried few times. Then I downloaded a package "amd-driver-installer-15.20.1046-x86.x86_64.run" from AMD site. And installed it both ways. At first when it offered to create specific package for the current system. And installed, there were 4 .deb  files. It didnt help. I tried to install in Automatic Mode. It installed successfully but still the problem is not solved.

Comment: No more ideas. Sry. The driver is OK.

Comment: when I triedcommand lspci -v it showed this output: 01:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun PRO [Radeon HD 8500M Series] (rev ff) (prog-if ff)
 !!! Unknown header type 7f
 Kernel driver in use: fglrx_pci
 Kernel modules: fglrx

Comment: sudo lspci -v -s 01:00.0 gives the same output.

Answer (score 0):

Normally the official AMD driver (*fglrx*) handle correctly hybrid systems.

Another way to go, is to force the use of the discrete card by using a custom `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`.

Some ressources to help you :

- [the documentation](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.7/doc/man/man5/xorg.conf.5.xhtml) on how to write this config file
- you can try to understand the configuration provided in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/657690/dead-parts-of-display/657701#657701)

Be careful, in the `Device` section you must use the adequate :

- driver used : `fglrx` for AMD official binary or `radeon` for opensource (best for 2D)
- `options` are relevant to driver you install, `man radeon` or `man fglrx` to see which options are available
- PCI bus obtained for you `01:00.0` given the result you provided of `lspci`